# Load data.json file for nunjucks with webpack

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, nunjucks

I'm looking for the similar way to inject data.json file for my nunjucks template with webpack.
With gulp would look something like this:

```
gulp.task('nunjucks', function(done) {
    return gulp.src(paths.src.templates + '/*.njk')
        .pipe(data(function() {
            return require('./data.json') 
        }))
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: paths.src.templates,
            envOptions: {
                lstripBlocks: true,
                autoescape: true,
                trimBlocks: true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.pages.base))
    done();
});
```

Any idea? I'm also using laravel-mix is that helps.

I thought I can do this, but didn't work:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: '/data.json',
            loader: 'json-loader',
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple-nunjucks-loader (I'm the author of it). Docs got example of integrating with html-webpack-plugin (for HTML files output) and passing data to it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-nunjucks-loader#with-html-webpack-plugin

```js
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var templateParameters = require('./data.json');

var htmlFiles = require('glob').sync(paths.src.templates + '/*.njk').map((file) => (
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: file,
    filename: file.replace('.njk', '.html'),
    templateParameters: templateParameters
  })
));


mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.njk$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'simple-nunjucks-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ 
    ...htmlFiles
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you Lesha. Although I can't see any data example. Can you give me one please?

Comment: It's the `templateParameters` in `html-webpack-plugin`

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work:
```mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.njk$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'simple-nunjucks-loader',
                    options: {}
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            templateParameters: require('./data.json')
        })
    ]
});``` based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639250/pass-json-file-from-html-webpack-plugin-to-handlebars-template, but I got "htmlWebpackPlugin is not defined"

Comment: Looks like you haven't import plugin. I have updated my answer with code example. I'm not yet sure what is a `mix` in your code, my example suggest that it is declared somewhere.

Comment: Each template that you want to compile should have separate instance of html-webpack-plugin

Comment: Mix is for laravel mix. Appreciate the answer and it's probably good, but I'm lost here. Don't really know how to fit into my code. You can have a look at here: https://gist.github.com/levipadre/e3a87682ed2cf7db98f089cba24d75f3

Comment: You can replace `nunjucks-webpack-plugin` with `html-webpack-plugin` and add `module` section from my example to have loader config

Comment: @ogonkov was really-really helpful and patient...legend.